# Weak limit of commuting self-adjoint operators is again commuting

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, operator-algebras

This question stems from 16.4 in [Zhu](https://books.google.dk/books?id=XHLj7bz8hOIC&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)'s book on operator algebras.

> Show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a self-adjoint set of commuting operators in $B(\mathcal{H})$, then
> the weak-operator closure of $\mathcal{A}$ consists again of mutually commuting
> operators.

My idea is the following. take two elements $S$ and $T$ in the weak closure of $\mathcal{A}$. We can approx. both elements with $T_\alpha \overset{w}{\to} T$ and $S_\alpha \overset{w}{\to} S$

choose some element $T_\alpha$ of the sequence and $S$.
We can approximate $S$ by some sequence $S_\beta$, so:
$$\langle T_\alpha S x,y \rangle=\lim_{\beta}\langle T_\alpha S_\beta x,y\rangle$$
since all the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ commute (and each element of the sequence is an element of $\mathcal{A}$) then
$$\lim_{\beta}\langle T_\alpha S_\beta x,y\rangle=\lim_{\beta}\langle S_\beta T_\alpha x,y\rangle=\langle S T_\alpha x,y\rangle$$

If we do the same for $T$ (writing it as a sequence of operators in $\mathcal{A}$ it will commute with any element $S_\alpha$) we get $\langle TS-STx,y\rangle=0$ which means $TS=ST$.

But this seems to prove things without using self-adjointness.
If so, where is this proof wrong?
In general, why do we need self-adjointness for which step of the proof?